# SpriteKit Animation doesn't work first time

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I'm making a game that has animation, and the animation doesn't work the first time I load the app. However, once I quit and open the app again, it works flawlessly. What's going on the first time?

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    background.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    addChild(background)

    TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"trumphappy")

    for i in 1...TextureAtlas.textureNames.count{
        var Name = "trumphappy\(i).png"
        TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))

    }
    HappyTrump = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"trumphappy1.png")
    HappyTrump.size = CGSize(width: 90, height: 150)
    HappyTrump.position = CGPoint(x: 5, y: 40)
    self.HappyTrump.zPosition = 1.0
    self.addChild(HappyTrump)


}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        HappyTrump.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: TextureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
    }
```

Comment: Why are you loading your textures that way?

Comment: `TextureArray.append(TextureAtlas.textureNamed("trumphappy\(i)")` and    `HappyTrump = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"trumphappy1"))`  You do not include the extension.  Note  `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"trumphappy1")` should be pulling from your atlas first, then check the file system for an image itf it does not exist

Comment: I watched a video about animation on spritekit and thats the way the guy in the video did it. What's the correct way to load them?

Comment: I gave it to you

Comment: when I  replace TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name)) in the for loop with  
TextureArray.append(TextureAtlas.textureNamed("trumphappy\(i‌​)") I get an error saying use of unresolved identifier 'i'

Comment: you still need the forloop

Comment: your code did not copy correctly,  you have trumphappy0;i

Comment: for some reason when I copy what you posted, i get that on stackoverflow. but on xcode it is the same as what you posted and I still get the error..

Comment: I know you are new at programming, but problems like this you need to learn to figure out on your own if you plan on succeeding.  The compiler is telling you that 'i' does not exist, what do you think that means?